# The regular representation of $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ is indecomposable but not irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, representation-theory

Let, $F = G = \mathbb{Z}_{3}$. We then let $V$ be an $FG$ module where $G$ is a basis for $V$, and the action is:
$$g' \cdot g = g'g, ~ ~ g \in G, g'\in V.$$

We then obtain the representation, $\phi:G \rightarrow GL_{3}(V)$, where:
\begin{align}0 &\mapsto \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right),\;\; \\
1 &\mapsto \left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right), \\
2 &\mapsto \left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right).
\end{align}

Consider the characteristic polynomial of $\phi(1)$, it is $1-x^3.$ We have that, $1-x^3$ does not split over the field $F$; hence, $\phi(1)$ is not diagonalizable which implies it is indecomposable.

Let,
$$I = \{\alpha_1[0]_{3} + \alpha_2[1]_{3} + \alpha_3 [2]_{3}: \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 = 0, \alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3 \in F \}.$$
Observe that $I$ is a submodule of $V$. We have that,
$$ 2[0]_{3} + 1[2]_{3} \in I \implies I \ne 0.$$
We have that,
$$1 [2]_{3} \not \in I \implies I \ne V.$$

Hence, $V$ is not irreducible.

Does my proof look good? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand this at all. $\phi(0)$ is visibly diagonal. And $1-x^3=(1-x)^3$ splits.

Comment: I don't think you mean $V=G$ (as set), you maybe mean the set $G$ is a basis of $V$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician, ah you are right sorry dumb mistake by me, duh. I will post a fix in a few.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, ok there is a bit of a mistake in your comment but it is mostly my fault, note that $1-x^3 \ne (1-x)^3$. The char polynomial of $\phi(0)$ is indeed $(1-x)^3$, for some reason I said $(1-x^3)$, but the char polynomial of $\phi(1)$ is $1-x^3$, so now my conclusion follows.

Comment: You are working over the field of $3$ elements are you not? So $(1-x^3)=(1-x)^3$. All your matrices have characteristic polynomial $(1-x))^3$; the first has minimal polynomial $(1-x)$ the other two minimal polynomial $(1-x)^3$ so are not diagonalisable. But all commute, so possess and common eigenvector: which yields a proper submodule.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, I see now, yes big mistake on my part by not realizing we are working over $Z_{3}$ and we have the freshman's dream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your submodule $I$ is indeed a proper non-trivial submodule, but your preliminaries are confused (and even after editing still wrong).

But you have now recognised in the comments $1-X^3=(1-X)^3$ over the field of three elements.

The characteristic polynomial of $\phi(1)$ is then $(1-X)^3$ and its minimal polynomial is $(1-X)^3$ (as $(Id-\phi(1))^2\ne O$): hence $\phi(1)$ has a $1$-eigenvector, although it is not diagonalisable. This eigenvector will span a $1$-dimensional submodule since $1$ is a generator of the group $G$. Hence the regular representation is not irreducible.

Actually more can (and ought to be said).

It is clear that $[0]+[1]+[2]$ spans the only  $1$-dimensional submodule.

It is easy to see that {$[0]+[1]+[2], [0]+2[1]\}$ spans the only $2$-dimensional submodule. This is your submodule $I$.

From this we have indecomposability: the sum of the unique $1$-dimensional submodule and the unique $2$-dimensional submodule is not the whole space.

Comment: I'm curious, how do you know that spans the only two dimensional submodule? Thanks!

Comment: One way to see that is to notice that the minimal polynomial of the generator must be $(1-X)^2$ on a 2-dimensional submodule; if there are two of them they generate the 3-dimensional space and so the min poly would be $(1-X)^2$ on the whole space and it's not. All this is just what the theory of the JCF tells us about the structure of $k[X]/\langle X^m\rangle$ as $k[X]$ module.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/3$ with basis $(e_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}/3}$ and the operator $T$, $T(e_i) = e_{i+1}$ ( this is the action of $\hat 1 \in \mathbb{Z}/3$ in the regular representation). In $\operatorname{char} 3$, $T$ is a unipotent operator. Indeed we have
$$
\begin{align}T(e_0 + e_1 + e_2)&= &e_0 + e_1 + e_2& \\
T( e_2 - e_1)  &= &(e_2 - e_1)& + (e_0 + e_1 + e_2)\\
T(e_1) & =& e_1 + (e_2 - e_1)&\end{align}$$
that is, for the basis $(f_0, f_1, f_2) = (e_0 + e_1 + e_2, e_2-e_1, e_1)$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
T (f_0) &= f_0 \\
T(f_1) &= f_1 + f_0 \\
T(f_2) &= f_2 + f_1
\end{align}$$

We therefore can write $T = I + N$, where  $N f_i = f_{i-1}$.

The invariant subspaces of $T$ are those of $N$. Now, consider a vector $v = f_i + c f_{i-1} + \cdots$. Then we can see that $(N^k v)_{k \ge 0}$ generates the subspace $V_i \colon =\langle f_i, f_{i-1}, \ldots, f_0\rangle$.  We conclude that the only invariant subspaces of $T$ are $(V_i)_{-1\le i \le 2}$. Therefore, the action of $T$ is not completely reducible.